# Even margin spacing between div elemtents inside of another div element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get an even spacing between `divs` inside a div with a set width of max the containing elements and this `div` is in another `div` which contains the other two and is set to `width 60%`.
You can see the 4 `divs` which are in a bigger div that holds all the 4 `divs`. The bigger div has a width of 60%. I tried to make a  % `margin` to the right but even at 1% one of the `img` gets in the next line and I don't want that.
I also tried `margin:auto`, `align-items:center` and some other stuff but nothing worked and most of them didn't do anything. Note that I don't want to use any responsive web design things like `flexbox`!
`div` order.

```css
.container {
  width: 60%;
  /*This is the biggest one and contains everything from the side that has to be in the center*/
  margin: auto;
}

.container1 {
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
}

.angebotTop {
  display: inline-block;
  width: max-content;
}

.angebote {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px auto 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Unterkünfte rund um die Welt</h2>
<div class="container1">
  <div class="angebotTop">
    <div class="angebote">
      <img src="Bilder/Airbnb/hotel-2.jpg" alt="">
      <p id="angebot">GANZE WOHNUNG &#11825; KOPENHAGEN</p>
      <p id="beschreibung">Sonniges Penthouse mit 5 Balkonen</p>
      <p id="preis">206€ pro Nacht</p>
      <p id="bewertung">&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733; 320</p>

    </div>
    <div class="angebote">
      <img src="Bilder/Airbnb/hotel-3.jpg" alt="">
      <p id="angebot">GANZES HAUS &#11825; FUJIEDA</p>
      <p id="beschreibung">Yui Valley-Traditional <br> House</p>
      <p id="preis">89€ pro Nacht</p>
      <p id="bewertung">&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733; 220</p>
    </div>
```

[I marked the divs with blue lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8QNU.png)

Comment: Flexbox can used to implement responsive designs, but that is not its main purpose. You definitely shouldn't reject it based on that assumption. Both `display: flex` and `display: grid` are the missing layout techniques that have forced people into approaches like yours, which are much harder to understand, implement and maintain, and tend to be very instable with regard to future changes. Regressions are just too easy to introduce on the way.

Comment: As an additional note, I've turned your code example into a runnable snippet in hope that you might edit it so it reproduces your issue. For the missing images I suggest you use a [*free image placeholder service*](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=free+image+placeholder+service). Please also fix the two unclosed `div` elements in your markup. Last sidenote: Using non-English class names or variable/function names makes it harder for people on Stack Overflow to help. I recommend switching to English if possible.

Comment: Third note, because I initially didn't notice: You have duplicate `id`s in your markup, which renders your HTML invalid and is bound to cause alot of problem when you try to work with your MARKUP in Javascript. Make sure you never use any given `id` value more than once per-document. If you need those for styling these elements, use CSS classes instead.

Answer (score 1):

These two div's are spaced evenly. You can either use flex or grid to achieve it. Make sure that the div are direct children of flex if you want them to align evenly. You can use flex-wrap to move the successive divs below;

```css
.container{
            width:60%;
            margin:auto;              
        }

      .container1{
        display: flex;
        margin: 15px 15px 15px 0px; 
        margin: 0 auto;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        
        }
        .angebote{
            width: 250px;
            height: 300px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Unterkünfte rund um die Welt</h2>
        <div class="container1">
                <div class="angebote">
                    <img  src="Bilder/Airbnb/hotel-2.jpg" alt="">
                    <p id="angebot">GANZE WOHNUNG &#11825; KOPENHAGEN</p>
                    <p id="beschreibung" >Sonniges Penthouse mit 5 Balkonen</p>
                    <p id="preis">206€ pro Nacht</p>
                    <p id="bewertung">&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733; 320</p>

                </div>
                <div class="angebote">
                    <img src="Bilder/Airbnb/hotel-3.jpg" alt="">
                    <p id="angebot">GANZES HAUS &#11825; FUJIEDA</p>
                    <p id="beschreibung">Yui Valley-Traditional <br> House</p>
                    <p id="preis">89€ pro Nacht</p>
                    <p id="bewertung">&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733; 220</p>
                </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I said I don't want to use flexbox and now the only solution here is flexbox or am I missing something ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read that you didn't want flexbox. You can use a polyfill then if you want to align the items without using the flexbox or grid. Here is the [link](https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility) to the polyfill. Are you targeting an older browser?

Comment: I'm not targeting anything, it is just a project to learn the basic of html and css and earn some experience in it. After that I will target responsive webdesign and then js. I will look into polyfill but was hoping for something easy, maybe I should just skip that for now.